# Get data from the signed file when using Docusign

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pdf, docusignapi

I am using Docusign (REST API) with ASP.NET MVC to display the document in embedded view when the user clicks on a button. When the user signs the document and clicks finish I should be able to get the data in the signed PDF (such as signature, name and other details). I looked into different documentations, but not sure of how to extract the data.

Can any one please help me with that?
Thanks.

Comment: If you have any code you have tried already - it's a good idea to post it here.

Comment: Do you want to show the signing ceremony to the recipients to want to show the signed PDF?

Comment: Hi @AmitKBist, when the user signs the PDF and clicks submit, I should be able to get the data they filled into the PDF such as signature, name etc. Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

You can get the FormData from a Signed Envelope using
`GET /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/form_data` as explained here, https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeFormData/get/ or you can use DocuSign connect as well to push the data to your listeners

https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-webhooks-dont-poll-us-well-call/